# In nodejs once the module have been loaded is it possible to unload the modules?

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm

```
app.post('/userlogin',function(req,res){

var Module1=require('./lib/module1');
    app.use(Module1);
var Module2=require('./lib/module2');
    app.use(Module2);
});
```

Once the modules have been loaded, can they be unloaded or destroyed? 
Example:

```
app.get('/logout',function(req,res){

// some function to unload the modules  
})
```

Comment: I don't know if you really want to do that. It seems a lot of work for something, in my opinion, unnecessary.

Maybe you can tell us why you want to do that?

Comment: 'var Module1=require('./lib/module1') app.use(Module1)' ; the module contains routing to certain location (eg:localhost:1000/testpage ). What I want is once /logout has been initiated the routing (localhost:1000/testpage) shouldn't take place. I tried using the above mention approach but I am still able to route once the module has been unloaded , This is what i want to achieve

Comment: I think you should not achieve this by adding and removing functionality. This should be done with a security context, where you only allow a access to 'testpage' if the user is signed in.

Comment: I want to load modules specific to users, i.e when user A logs in he can load module 1 and module 2, while user B can load module 2 only. As a result, i was trying to keep the '/logout' in such a way that on routing '/logout' all loaded modules are unloaded irrespective of the user

Comment: And exactly this behaviour (User A has access to module 1 & 2, User B has only access to module 2) should be handled with access restrictions. Adding and removing actual functionality to "simulate" this behaviour should definitely be avoided, as it has a huge impact on system resources and it's just not the way how it's done :)

Comment: ok, I will go ahead and add access restrictions specific to users. Ty :)

Comment: You are welcome. You'll see the advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Adding and removing functionality is absolutely not a solution for access restrictions based on a users, as multiple users may use the system at once.
Also is very prone to errors, it's a massive intervention and will have a massive impact on the server system.

A security context will take care of all that, without messing with your system, as it's just added on top of it.